# flutter decode json data into list of objects

Tags: json, flutter

i am trying to decode json data into a list of objects to use it later with provider,i didn't received any error but the list is still empty.
here is my code for know:

```
class Mobile {
final String name;
final String camera;
final String cpu;
final String price;
final String memory;
final String battery;
Mobile({this.name,this.camera,this.cpu,this.memory,this.battery,this.price});
}

     class MobilesData extends ChangeNotifier {
     List<Mobile> _mobiles = [
     ];

 Future<void> fetchmob() async{
const url='http://10.0.2.2/mobitech/index.php';
try{
  final response=await http.get(url);
  final exctractedData=jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
  final List<Mobile> loadedMob=[];
  exctractedData.forEach((mobData){
    loadedMob.add(Mobile(
      name: mobData['name'],
      camera: mobData['system'],
      memory: mobData['cpu'],
      cpu: mobData['gpu'],
      battery: mobData['battery'],
      price: mobData['price_eg'],
    ));
  });
  print("exctractedData:$exctractedData");
  print("loadedMob:$loadedMob");
  _mobiles=loadedMob;
  print("_mobiles:$_mobiles");
  notifyListeners();
}catch(error){
  throw error;
}
 }
List<Mobile> get mobiles{
return [..._mobiles];
 }
}
```

the output of get mobiles method,exctractedData list,loadedMob list,mobiles list:

```
I/flutter (28994): Instance of 'Future<void>'
I/flutter (28994): get mobiles method output:[]
I/flutter (28994): exctractedData:[{mob_id: 1, name: Find x50, screen: 6.5 
inches PLS TFT capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors., screen_protect: Gorilla 
glass 3., screen_res: 720 x 1600 pixels, 20:9 ratio (~270 ppi density)., 
system: Android 10, One UI 2.0., cpu: Octa-core (4x2.0 GHz Cortex-A55 & 4x2.0 
GHz Cortex-A55)., num_core: Octa-core., gpu: Mali-G52., memory: 32/64 GB. , 
ram: 3/4/6 GB., battery: 5000 mAh., camera_main: 48 MP., camera_feature: LED 
flash, panorama, HDR., camera_video: 1080p@30fps., camera_ultra: 8 MP, f/2.2, 
123˚, 1/4.0", 1.12µm., camera_tele: none, camera_depth: 2 MP, f/2.4., 
camera_micro: 2 MP, f/2.4., camera_self: 13 MP, f/2.2, (wide), 1/3.1", 
1.12µm, camera_self_feature: LED flash., camera_self_video: 1080p@30fps, 
price_eg: unavailable, price_sa: unavailable, price_uae: unavailable, 
price_jo: unavailable, price_sy: 220000 S.P, price_alg: unavailable, mob_cat: 
2}, {mob_id: 2, name: Galaxy A71, screen: 6.7 inches Super AMOLED Plus 
capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors., screen_protect: Corning Gorilla Glas
I/flutter (28994): loadedMob:[Instance of 'Mobile', Instance of 'Mobile']
I/flutter (28994): _mobiles:[Instance of 'Mobile', Instance of 'Mobile']
```

Comment: print `extractedData` and post the result.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore extractedData returned list like this [{mob_id: 1, name: Find x50, screen: 6.5 inches PLS TFT capacitive touchscreen,},{mob_id: 2, name: Galaxy A71, screen: 6.7 inches Super AMOLED Plus capacitive touchscreen,}] but it's too long to put it in this comment

Comment: Please post that as an edit in your question, not as a comment.

Comment: You're overwriting `_mobiles` which is the list you're filling in your forEach loop. So you end up losing the data you wrote in the forEach. Just remove this line:
`_mobiles=loadedMob;`

Comment: first i tried to use loadedMob but when it didn't works i tried to use _mobiles list and i forget to correct the code before posting my question

Comment: What's the first thing you're printing?

Comment: i printed each list separately, i placed the print command after the forEach loop

Comment: Please post the **exact** code that you're using

Comment: i will edit my question with the exact code i am using